# R: How to fix perpetual "Click or hit ENTER for next page" on plot()?

Tags: windows, r

I'm using Windows 7x64 and R v2.14.2, with revolution R as the GUI.

For some reason, every time I make a `plot`, the console states:

```
Waiting to confirm page change...
```

...and the plot states:

```
Click or hit ENTER for next page
```

I have to click somewhere in the plot to allow it to complete its plot.

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong, and is there any way to fix this without reinstalling R in its entirety?

**Update 1**

I've tried:

```
devAskNewPage(FALSE)
options(device.ask.default = FALSE)
grDevices::devAskNewPage(ask=FALSE)
```

Here is my list of windows:

```
> dev.list()
windows 
      2
```

I think this problem started after I used `plot.new()` to create a new graphics window. My machine was also shut down non-gracefully last night. On another odd note, the graphics work (albeit oddly) in Revolution R, but don't display at all in RStudio, even though this uses a different core R version (v2.15.2).

**Update 2**

I'm wondering if there is a way to set `par()` to its installation defaults?

**Update 3**

Rebooted machine; problem still exists.

Comment: Maybe try to reinstall Windows ?... Don't downvote, I'm just kidding !

Comment: have you tried `par(ask=FALSE)` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one was definitely user error; both Windows and R are working perfectly.

The problem was with the plot command in a sub-function:

```
plot(y ~ a + b)
```

This command does not plot two series on one graph; it plots them separately on two graphs, with the message "Click or hit ENTER for next page” between them. All of the other precursors/symptoms were simple coincidence.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you need to close the graphics device and open a new one before changes to `devAskNewPage` or `getOption("device.ask.default")` take effect.

At a guess, you are calling some code where asking for to change the plot is turned on, and then trying to create more plots in the same device.

Comment: Your guess was absolutely correct: I was using plot(y ~ a + b) which will always display this message.

Comment: not sure why your answer was not selected. It help me.